# New Wordpress plugin - Administrator can't access settings page

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, content-management-system

first of all I'll say that I'm new in WordPress plugin development.
I'm trying to add a simple Settings page for my plugin. It is showing up correctly in the dashboard menu, but if I access that page clicking the link it will load an empty page with the error message: "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

I am using WordPress 3.9.1 and I'm following this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668.

What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
<?php
    /**
     *
     * Gestionale WinterTour
     *
     * Plugin per gestire i tornei e l'anagrafica e le iscrizioni dei membri
     * @author Comunico S.r.l. <info@comunico.info>
     * @version 1.0
     * @package wintertour
     *
     * Plugin Name: Gestionale WinterTour
     * Plugin URI: http://www.sporthappenings.it/gestionale/
     * Description: Plugin per gestire i tornei e l'anagrafica e le iscrizioni dei membri
     * Version: 1.0
     * Author: Comunico S.r.l.
     * Author URI: http://www.comunico.info/
     * License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
     * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
     *
     * This plugin, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
     */

    /**
     * Admin menu handler
     */
    function wintertour_admin() {
        include ('wintertour_import_admin.php');
    }

    /**
     * Add options page handler
     */
    function wintertour_admin_actions() {
        add_options_page("Gestionale WinterTour", "Gestionale WinterTour", 1, "Gestionale WinterTour", "wintertour_admin");
    }

    add_action('admin_menu', 'wintertour_admin_actions');
?>
```

EDIT: the "wintertour_import_admin.php" is empty and it's not relevant here.. I should get a empty page in my settings page and still seeing the dashboard menu..

Even if I put basic html in it like `<h1>Hello!</h1>` it won't show up.. I just get an empty white page saying "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." and I don't see any dashboard menu. Even if I print stuff inside te wintertour_admin() function.

Thanks in advance!
Zorgatone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the slug (i.e. 4th parameter of `add_options_page` function) one word instead of two, it will work properly:

`add_options_page("Gestionale WinterTour", "Gestionale WinterTour", 1, "GestionaleWinterTour", "wintertour_admin");`

Comment: Ahahah I feel so dumb.. xD
It fixed!! Thankss :D